# convert String to Arraylist using json

Tags: java, json, arraylist, gson

I have a situation where I want to convert a string into an `ArrayList` that contains integers and other `ArrayList`s. In my string, I can have an arbitrary number of words which I want added into the ArrayList object:

```
String s = "[2,5,9,8,1,[5,7],9,8,[9,6,9,8],8,9]";
```

When I try this, it doesn't seem to work:

```
String jsonString = "[5,5],6,[2,5]";
        Gson gson=new Gson();

        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> yourArray = gson.
fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayList< String>>>() {}.getType());
```

Comment: how many level of arrays you will have from your arbitrary number of words ?

Comment: Probably missing brackets

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a JSON string, so you can't convert it. A proper JSON string has to have key and value pairs, within brackets.

```
 String s = "{Array : [2,5,9,8,1,[5,7],9,8,[9,6,9,8],8,9]}";
```